# Inconsistent coastlines() results when using the cartopy keyword 'central_longitude()'

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I'm working with observational geospatial (ISCCP) data in python using xarray for handling and plotting. The data are on a 144-entry 2.5° grid beginning with 1.25°E, so longitude gridpoints are 1.25, 3.75, 6.25, etc., culminating at 358.75°E. When I plot other data, for example, MERRA-2 reanalysis data on a 2.5° grid using the central_longitude keyword in my projection like below, it properly centers both data and coastlines at the desired longitude.

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
merra = xr.open_dataset(...)
a = merra.OMEGA.plot.contourf(subplot_kws=dict(projection=
                              ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=179.9999999999994),
                              transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
a.axes.coastlines()
```

The output to this looks like this, with certain important markers clearly visible that indicate the data was transformed correctly. [image: Example of correctly projected/transformed data]

However, applying the same technique to the other data yields clearly incorrect results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
isccp = xr.open_dataset(...)
a = isccp.lcf.mean(dim=['time', 'tau']).plot(subplot_kws=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=179.75),
                                                              transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
a.axes.coastlines()
```

[image: Example of INcorrectly projected/transformed data]

You can clearly see the outline of data from Africa in what should be the central/eastern Pacific, and data from South America in the Maritime Continent.

Where is the problem arising? Is it in the way I'm applying the transform/projection? Could it be an import order issue? In rewriting my code for this post, I'm seeing that the two different python files have a different order in which I imported the libraries, so I included that in the above code blocks. I know that that sort of thing can lead to errors, especially when plotting using xarray is concerned.

Comment: You're not really applying a transform but assigning it, so it really depends on your data (which you didn't share so it's anybody's guess). What happens when you also add the `central_longitude` to the transform, eg `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=179.75)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've solved (?) the problem. Someone with more technical knowledge of the inner workings of how xarray/cartopy/matplotlib interact with eachother might want to fact check me, but by first creating a subplots object with

```
subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=179.75),
                                        transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

in its keywords and then use

```
data.variable.plot.contourf(ax=[row,col],
                            projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=179.75),
                            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

to make each individual plot, I get correctly aligned data and coastlines. Probably arising as a result of something I'm doing wrong, but if not, hopefully this can help somebody!